# Replace Character across multiple docs

Tags: regex

I have multiple docs that contain a value, for example:

> Asset_ID="PTLV0000000123456791" Asset_Class="TITLE"

Or

> Asset_ID="PTLV0000000123456801" Asset_Class="TITLE"

I need to replace the first part of the string (`PTLV0`) with `PTLV1`.
The search I have - **Asset_ID="PTLV0.*?" Asset_Class="TITLE"**
But not sure on how to replace in order to preserve the remaining part of the thread?

Comment: What **language/editor** are you doing this in?

Comment: Do you need regex for this?  What is the possibility of having the substring `"PTLV0"` and it not being the string you want to change?

Comment: This is in Notepad++

Comment: Just use a simple string replace: replace `Asset_ID="PTLV0` for `Asset_ID="PTLV1`. Much simpler

Comment: I can't use a simple search and replace since I have some other similar values that I can't change. For example, Asset_ID="PTLV0000000123456792" Asset_Class="MOVIE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My default instinct is to find `PTLV0` and replace with `PTLV1`, because it seems a lot easier than bothering with regexes.

BUT.  On the off chance that you NEED to match on a string with asset_class and what not along with the ID itself, you can use lookbehinds and lookaheads to match text before and after the intended match without including it in the match itself.

For example:

- (?<=foo)bar matches the "bar" in "foobar", but not in "ackbar" or just "bar"
- foo(?=bar) matches the "foo" in "foobar", but not in "foodstuff" or just "foo"

So you could use a regex like `(?<=Asset_ID="PTLV)0(?=\d+" Asset_Class="TITLE")` to match just the zero, and replace with `1`.